# TCP Socket: Data Transfer from Python Client to Java Server on Android Studio is Extremly Slow

Tags: python, android, sockets, tcp

I am sending image bytes (around 4Mb) over from my Python client, on my computer, to my Java Server, running on an Android Tablet. The Python client sends all the data in a fraction of a second while the Java server takes over 2 seconds to read all the data. This is too slow for my needs.  I tried using a BufferedInputStream to resolve the issue but no luck.

If anyone has any ideas on how to correct this, or maybe a different method other than TCP for sending large amounts of data, I would love to hear them!  I've attached my code below

Python Client Code (Running on PC):

```
client_address = (client_ip_address, client_port)
cs_display = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
cs_display.connect(client_address)
while True:
        image1 = open("res/image1.bmp","rb")
        image2 = open("res/image2.bmp","rb")
        image = [image1, image2]
        used_image = image[counter]
        bytes = used_image.read()
        size = len(bytes)
        print("File bytes: ", size)
        cs_display.sendall(size.to_bytes(4, byteorder='big'))
        print("sent")
        buff = cs_display.recv(4)
        resp = int.from_bytes(buff, byteorder ="big")
        print("Response: ", resp)
        if size  == resp:
            print("Trying to send message")
            cs_display.sendall(bytes)
        counter += 1
        counter = counter%2
```

Java Client (Running on Android):

```
    class DisplayThread implements Runnable{
        Socket s;
        ServerSocket ss;
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                ss = new ServerSocket(5002);
                s = ss.accept();
                OutputStream sout = s.getOutputStream();
                BufferedInputStream sin = new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                while(true)
                {
                    // Get length
                    byte[] size_buff = new byte[4];
                    sin.read(size_buff);
                    int size = ByteBuffer.wrap(size_buff).asIntBuffer().get();
                    System.out.format("Expecting %d bytes\n", size);

                    // Send it back
                    sout.write(size_buff);
                    // Create Buffers
                    byte[] msg_buff = new byte[size];
                    byte[] img_buff = new byte[size];
                    while(true) {
                        int bytes_read = 0;
                        try {
                            bytes_read = sin.read(msg_buff, 0, size);
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            System.out.print(e);
                        }
                        if(bytes_read == -1) { break; }

                        // Copy bytes into img_buff
                        try {
                            System.arraycopy(msg_buff, 0, img_buff, img_offset, bytes_read);
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            System.out.print(e);
                        }
                        img_offset += bytes_read;

                        if(img_offset >= size) { break; }
                    }
                }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Failed to accept");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is buggy: `sin.read(size_buff)`. `read` returns an int which you are throwing away. I recommend you acquaint yourself with the DataInputStream/DataOutputStream classes. It has methods like `readInt()` that would be both correct and much simpler than your current code. `readFully` could be used to completely eliminate the inner while loop.

Comment: I am a little confused why I would need the int returned from sin.read(size_buff), is that not just the number of bytes read?  That data is not really useful to me I thought.

Comment: You don't know how many bytes were read, that's why you have to examine the return value. You need to loop until all 4 bytes are read.

Comment: Oh ok I see how that could cause issuies.  I will also look into that readFully.  Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I used the ReadFully method and it speed up transmission by about 20-30% but it is still too slow.  Could it be because I am using a wireless connection?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really have any more suggestions. Perhaps an Android expert can stop by and offer suggestions on how to pinpoint the source of performance problems.

Comment: You should use `DataInputStream.readInt()` to read the size word, instead of all this homegrown code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on Android, but if I may hazard a guess at the problem I would guess that since you're sending receiving an image it's possible that the image is large and Android is giving your app less priority because it's using a lot of memory. Note that you are using twice as much memory as you need because you have two arrays that are the size of the image:

```java
byte[] msg_buff = new byte[size];
byte[] img_buff = new byte[size];
```

where only one is needed. Here is a shorter rewrite of your method using the DataInputStream/DataOutputStream classes that gets rid of the extra array and thus halves the memory.

```
    public void run2() {
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(5002);
            s = ss.accept();
            DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()));

            // Get length

            int size = dIn.readInt();
            System.out.format("Expecting %d bytes\n", size);
            
            // Send it back
            
            dOut.writeInt(size);
            dOut.flush();
            
            // Get image

            byte [] img_buff = new byte[size];
            dIn.readFully(img_buff);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to accept");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Good point.  Even with the change though it still lacks in performance.  I feel it is just limitations of the hardware.  But it still achieves around 2Mbps download speed which is good enough for my uses.